# Как сделать статистику просмотров и загрузок php по датам

Tags: php

У меня есть скрипты для ведения статистика просмотра сайта и скачивания определенного файла с этого же сайта.Мне нужно,чтобы выводилось не просто значение сколько всего было просмотрено/скачено.А сколько было просмотрено за все время/за сегодня и сколько было скачено за все время/за сегодня

*Cкрипт для статистики просмотров*

```
          <?

       // Имя файла, в котором хранится счетчик
         $file_counter = "counter.txt";

         // Читаем текущее значение счетчика
          if (file_exists($file_counter)) {
             $fp = fopen($file_counter, "r");
      $counter = fread($fp, filesize($file_counter));
       fclose($fp);
            } else {
      $counter = 0;
        }
             // Увеличиваем счетчик на единицу
            $counter++;

              // Сохраняем обновленное значение счетчика
         $fp = fopen($file_counter, "w");
     fwrite($fp, $counter);
      fclose($fp); 


          ?>
```

*Cкрипт для статистики cкачиваний файла*

```
   <?php

if ($_GET['book']==1) {
header("location: /zip.zip"); //здесь указываете путь 
 к файлу, который нужно скачать
$file=fopen("book.txt","a+"); //book1.txt - это им¤ файла, в котором будет 
 хранитьс¤ статистика закачек
flock($file,LOCK_EX); 
$count=fread($file,100);
$count++; 
ftruncate($file,0); 
fwrite($file,$count); 
flock($file,LOCK_UN); 
fclose($file); 
}
?>
```

Comment: Записывайте в файл по строкам или через запятую дату вместо количества. Потом читайте этот файл, делайте explode() по разделителю. Получаете массив. Ну а дальше уже дело за малым.

Comment: И лучше писать не в файл, а в базу данных, т.к. пока один процесс читает и записывает изменившееся значение счетчика, другие процессы не могут получить к нему доступа.

Answer (score 2):

> Для начала пара слов о коде: Если у PHP скрипта в конце после `?>`
>   ничего не идёт - не ставьте закрывающий `?>`, вместо него должна быть
>   пустая строка. Начальный же (открывающий) тег всегда следует писать
>   как `<?php`

Просто по одному числу определить статистику закачек не очень легко. т.е. вообще не легко. мало кто может так сделать. Для этого (предположим что вы вообще ни в какую не собираетесь использовать для таких целей БД) заведём файл с немного другой структурой и другими данными и иначе обработаем его.

```
<?php

class Stat {

  protected $fname;

  public function __construct($fname) {
    // Сохраним путь к файлу
    $this->fname = $fname;
  }

  /**
  * Добавляет в конец файла текущий unix TIMESTAMP
  *
  * @return bool true
  */
  public function increase() {
    // Откроем поток для записи
    // И поставим указатель в конец файла
    $f = fopen($this->fname, 'c');
    // Запишем текущее время в UNIX TIMESTAMP формате
    fwrite($f, round(microtime(true)));
    // Закроем поток
    fclose($f);

    return true;
  }

  /**
  * Читает файл и получает кол-во строк,
  * где время больше или равно $start
  *
  * @param string $start - время начала
  *
  * @return int - кол-во строк
  */
  public function getCountFrom($start = 0) {
    // Откроем поток для чтения
    $f = fopen($this->fname, 'c+');
    // Определим счётчик как 0
    $counter = 0;
    // Пока не достигнем конца файла
    while(!feof($f)) {
      // Читаем строку
      $line = (int) trim(fgets($f));
      // Если число больше $time
      if($line > $start) {
        // Увеличим счётчик
        $counter++;
      }
    }
    // закроем поток чтения
    fclose($f);
    // вернём результат
    return $counter;
  }

  /**
  * Обращается к self::getCountFrom,
  * с параметром $start = время сегодня
  *
  * @return int - кол-во строк
  */
  public function getCountToday() {
    // берём время начала дня
    $today = mktime(0,0,0);
    // получаем и возвращаем результаты
    return $this->getCountFrom($today);
  }

}


// Далее используем где надо
$views_counter = new Stat(__DIR__ . '/views_counter.txt');
// Увеличиваем счётчик на 1
$views_counter->increase();
// Получаем кол-во записей за всё время
$total_views = $views_counter->getCountFrom();
// Получаем кол-во записей за сегодня
$today_views = $views_counter->getCountToday();
```

Comment: спасибо большое за такой развернутый ответ,но я все так и сделал,но в текстовик почему-то не приходит статистика,что я делаю не так ?

Comment: возможно проблема в правах доступа к файлу [chmod](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chmod), возможно вы указали не тот флаг при fopen, что приводит к очищению файла перед записью

Comment: не тот флаг ?А какой там нужен флаг ?)